# MySQL [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such fie or directory

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble starting `mysql` and `mysqld`.

Output of `sudo service mysql start` command is `mysql : Unrecognized service`

Same way output of `sudo service mysqld start` is nothing

When I tried `sudo service mysqld status` it says `stopped`

I went through `/var/log/mysql.log` found this error :

```
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1600607
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't create/write to fie '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such fie or directory
151020 08:00:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

For which I looked online and tried to fix issue which said to be of the permission, So I created to fix this error which `/var/run/mysqld` for `mysql.pid` and I did `chown` the directory to `mysql:mysql`

But still the problem persist.
Can anyone help me out with this!

Thanks

Comment: Check the /etc/my.cnf if under [mysqld] there is a property for user, which defines which user will be used as service owner. This user should be the owner of datadir.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, adding information about Linux flavor in use would help a lot in this case. command: "lsb_release -a" or checking /etc/redhat-release and /etc/debian_version would provide more details related to OS in question.

Can't write to file can be error from: permissions (ACL) if ownership + filemode for directory is correct: check with command "stat /var/run/mysqld"
(line starting with text "Access:")

Also check that disk & i-nodes aren't full (with df -H and df -iH).

Next check that logfile /var/log/syslog (debian/ubuntu) or /var/log/messages (redhat family) doesn't contain any other errors or SELinux messages.

SELinux may also be denying write: check if SELinux is enabled with command: "getenforce"

SELinux messages may also appear in /var/log/audit/audit.log, check it for any denied messages: "grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log"
If it gives any errors, see video https://youtu.be/cNoVgDqqJmM for quick tutorial on SELinux usage (specially the audit2allow)
If you see denied requests, you can see the reason with commandline: "grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -w"

This will explain all SELinux generated errors and hopefully may help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Tried it! not helpful 
Release is rhel 6.5

Comment: Can you paste here the stat command and make sure you checked free diskspace + free inodes + auditlog ?